# Check if endpoint is working and if is not, get another URL with axios

Tags: javascript, axios

I'm trying to learn about API consume with pokeapi and axios, and it seems like they are having problems with some end points, sometimes they are returning a 404 error. I want to use that error as to practice

I have the following code:

```
const pokemonDataList = []

for(i = 1; i ≤ quantity) {
    const url = `https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${i}/`
    pokemonDataList.push(await axios.get(url))
}
```

When I run that, everything works until a dead endpoint is accessed, then my local serve stop running and return a unhandled error message.

What I want to do is when the

> await axios.get(url)

gets an error, like 404 or 500, I want to be able to fetch from another end point, and then go back for my initial looping, so something like this:

const pokemonDataList = []

```
for(i = 1; i ≤ quantity) {
    const url = `https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${i}/`
    if(axios.get(url) === success) {
        pokemonDataList.push(await axios.get(url))
    } else {
        pokemonDataList.push(await axios.get(anotherUrl))
    }
}
```

Is there a way to do something like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If an error occurs during an axios call you can use try/catch to handle the error that occurred:

```
for(i = 1; i ≤ quantity) {
    const url = `https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${i}/`
    try{
        pokemonDataList.push(await axios.get(url))
    } 
    catch (error) {
        console.log(`Error occured on main endpoint ${url}: ${error.message}`);
        console.log(`Fetching data form: ${anotherUrl}`);
        pokemonDataList.push(await axios.get(anotherUrl));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the promises to handle the error, like so:

```
await axios.get(url).then((response) => {
   console.log(response);

   // Do something on success
}).catch((error) => {
   console.error(error);

   // Do something on error...
});
```